# How do i update a object in mongoDB via nodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I'm attempting to make it so that when a player gets a highscore it searches there name, then it adds that highscore to there account. My issue is I don't know how to search for a name and update a tag using mongoose?

Here is my server code:

```js
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var http = require("http").createServer(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(http);

var PORT = 3332;

app.use("/", express.static(__dirname));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/endg", {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.once("open", function (cb) {
  console.log("connection established");
});

io.on("connection", function (socket) {
  console.log("user connected");

  socket.on("chooseName", function (newName) {
    var data = {
      nickname: newName,
      highscore: 0,
    };
    db.collection("dat").findOne({ nickname: data.nickname }, function (
      err,
      doc
    ) {
      if (err) throw err;
      if (doc) {
        io.emit("nnTaken", null);
      } else {
        db.collection("dat").insertOne(data, function (err, coll) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log("rec estab");
          io.emit("newNickname", null);
        });
      }
    });
  });

  socket.on("player", function (player) {
    socket.on("highscore", function (hs) {
      console.log(player + ": " + hs);
      db.collection("dat").updateOne(
        { name: player },
        { $set: { highscore: hs } }
      );
      //This is where im trying to update but the above code does not work
    });
  });
});

http.listen(PORT, function () {
  console.log("server is up and running using port " + PORT);
});
```

How would i do this? I try using the update inside the highscore socket, so that when a highscore is achieved it updates that field but nothing is changing.

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured it out. I'll post the answer in case anyone has this issue in the future.

```js
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var http = require("http").createServer(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(http);

var PORT = 3332;

app.use("/", express.static(__dirname));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/endg", {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.once("open", function (cb) {
  console.log("connection established");
});

io.on("connection", function (socket) {
  console.log("user connected");

  socket.on("chooseName", function (newName) {
    var data = {
      nickname: newName,
      highscore: 0,
    };
    db.collection("dat").findOne({ nickname: data.nickname }, function (
      err,
      doc
    ) {
      if (err) throw err;
      if (doc) {
        io.emit("nnTaken", null);
      } else {
        db.collection("dat").insertOne(data, function (err, coll) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log("rec estab");
          io.emit("newNickname", null);
        });
      }
    });
  });

  socket.on("player", function (player) {
    socket.on("highscore", function (hs) {
      console.log(player + ": " + hs);
      db.collection("dat").findOne({ nickname: player }, function () {
        db.collection("dat").updateOne(
          { nickname: player },
          { $set: { highscore: hs } }
        );
      });
    });
  });
});

http.listen(PORT, function () {
  console.log("server is up and running using port " + PORT);
});
```

I went ahead and basically used findOne to find the players name, and then used updateOne with the $set to update the highscore value.

I'm guessing the issue was stemming from the fact that mongo wasn't able to tell which value i was trying to update.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you prefer async function with es6

```
socket.on('highscore', async highscore => {
  await db.collection('dat').findOneAndUpdate(
    { nickname: player },
    { $set: { highscore: hs } }
  )
});
```

I'm using ES6 Javascript syntax. `highscore => {}` is the same as `function (highscore)`
Also I'm using async function. `await` means the program wait until the function is done

Comment: I think to be able to use save() function, you have to define the Mongoose Model first. I've edited my code. It's basically the same as yours.